# How to have sliding divs in one single line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to use two divs which are in one single container. When I slide the first div to the left and then hide it, while showing the second div and sliding it left, the 2nd div is placed below the first, thereby breaking the page.

HTML Code

```
<div id="mainhomediv" class="maindiv">

</div>

<div id="mainhomediv1" class="maindiv">

</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.maindiv{
    min-height: 60%;
    max-height: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #435A43;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 30px #001A00;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 30px #001A00;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 30px #001A00;
    position: relative;
}
```

jQuery Script

```
$(function(){
    var counter=0;
    var divs=$('#mainhomediv,#mainhomediv1');
    function hideDiv(){
        divs.show().animate({'left': '-100%'},1000);
        divs.hide('fast');
        counter++;
    }
    function showDiv(){
        divs.filter(function(index){return index==counter%2;})
        .show('fast').animate({'left': '0%'},1000);
    }

    setInterval(function(){
        hideDiv();
        showDiv();
    },5*1000);
});
```

How can I slide each div left to right at intervals while keeping them on the same line?

Comment: I would probably wrap them in a container div and have them absolutely positioned, with the container div having overflow:hidden on it.

Comment: My container div is absolutely positioned itself, as a result of which changing the positioning of the maindiv breaks the page!

Comment: doesn't your maindiv class need to be absolute also though?

Comment: The maindiv is inside the container. I have set both to absolute. Thats how the page is structured.

Comment: looking at your CSS it states that .maindiv is relative positioned.

Comment: Yes sorry about the last comment. The container is absolute but the maindiv is relative. When I try to set the maindiv as absolute as well, it breaks the page!

Comment: does the container have to be absolute? If you try it with the container relative and the divs inside as absolute it shouldn't collapse up - you may need to set a height on the container though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `float:left;` to your css class.

Answer (score 0):

try this
http://jsfiddle.net/k4899/

```
 <div class="container">
 <div id="mainhomediv" class="maindiv">
      left div
  </div>

  <div id="mainhomediv1" class="maindiv">
       right div
    </div>

 </div> 



#mainhomediv{
  float:left;    
 }
  #mainhomediv1{
   float:right;
  }
```

Need to assign float left and right to your divs and wrap them in a container.

Comment: Cant do this mate. As the container is absolute, doing this breaks the page!

Comment: I know bro. It does work on the fiddle you just showed me. But when I try to assign the float to left and right respectively, it breaks the page!

Comment: add overflow:hidden to your container.

Answer (score 0):

animate/show/hide are some kind of **async** functions,  divs are not hide immediately after call divs.hide('fast'), there is a callback there.

```
divs.hide('fast', function(){
  //here the divs is hide
});
```

So if you want to hide -> show, move the show to the **callback** of hide.

I'm not sure this is what you want, but just try:

```
    $(function() {

        var counter = 0;
        var divs = $('#mainhomediv,#mainhomediv1');

        //make both left side
        divs.css({
            'left' : '-100%'
        });

        function showSomeDiv() {

            //the div to show
            var ds = divs.eq(counter % 2);

            //the div to hide
            var dh = divs.eq((counter + 1) % 2);

            dh.hide('fast', function() {

                //make it left side
                dh.css({
                    'left' : '-100%'
                });

                //slide ds out
                ds.show().animate({
                    'left' : '0%'
                }, 1000, function() {

                    counter++;

                    //do it again
                    setTimeout(showSomeDiv, 1000);
                });

            });
        }

        //Let's go
        showSomeDiv();
    });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit more? I understand I need a delay after the first div is hidden and the second is shown. How can I establish that?